# Ugee m708 Tablet - Cursor wont move

Tags: drivers, wacom

I am trying to get my UGEE M708 Tablet working with ubuntu, by default all the buttons work and clicking with the pen works, However if i try to use the pen to move the cursor it does nothing at all. Is there a way to get this to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no driver for this. I got model and name by running lsusb in terminal, it gave me the output of 5543:0081, I then googled this and looked for linux support, there is no driver available for it as of yet. Although it may detect it, hence why the buttons work, it doesnt detect the cursor movements and cannot function properly.

Shame.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 possible cases:

Case1. You can try this command in terminal: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`or if it's installed already, reinstall it with `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` .

Case2. Maybe you just disabled your touchpad accidentally. Try to enable it with the key combination(every device is not the same but normally Function key(Fn) with F_.（You can find some signs on the f_ keys).

Case3. Enable your touchpad with dconf-tools in case you can't find your touchpad hotkeys. Open the terminal and install `dconf-tools` with this command:`sudo apt-get install dconf-tools` and launch it. Navigate to this path:

```
org > gnome > settings-daemon > peripherals > touchpad
```

Check on `touchpad-enabled` to enable it. No root permission is needed in this case.

Comment: Ubuntu have drivers in default.Are you sure you ENABLED it by using method 2 and 3?

Comment: Yes, i tried those methods but there is no support for this particular tablet